# Drupal showing blank page after migrating to a local server

Tags: migrations, iis

(this question has been asked on Stackoverflow so I apologise for the repitition)

Firstly some background,..

IVe started a new job as PHP developer with a company that hosts 2 Drupal (6.x) sites.

While I have years of experience in PHP, Drupal ( and indeed off the shelf content management systems in general ) is a new one on me. Still, there is loads of documentation and its not rocket science, so no problems there.

The server environment is IIS (live server 7.0, locally 7.5) IIS is a totally new beast to me too, so it adds to teh learning curve.

I have successfully gotten a clean install of Drupal (7.x) to run locally, so I know the server is up and running correctly

The problem happens when I try to pull down the live site. I have replicated the database locally, and I know that it is connecting, however when I try to run the local site I get a blank page with the following source c ode:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
    <?include '_inc_head_common.tpl.php';?> 
  </head> 

  <body id="body"> 

      <?include '_inc_header.tpl.php';?> 
      <?include '_inc_content_3col.tpl.php';?> 
      <?include '_inc_footer.tpl.php';?> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

So it seems that it is getting to a point and no further..

has anyone encountered this before or could someone point me in the direction that I should be looking at?

Thanks

Kevin

Comment: did you clear all cache and run dabase update?

Comment: I cleared the cache by emptying the cache tables in the databse. How do I run database update?

Comment: load this url: **localhost/yourSiteFolder/update.php**. You should also run the status report to check up any error: **localhost/yourSiteFolder/admin/reports/status**

Comment: have you turned on Error reporting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using PHP shorthand. Can you change it to a proper  and see if that helps? Please see if the path is correct since drupal is using relative path (base_url, base_path). Also please update the $base_url in the settings.php if you have.

Comment: The issue was that in my php.ini file 'short_open_tag' was set to off. changing this to 'on' resolved my issue. Accepting your answer for putting me on the right track. Can you please clarify how to check my path? thanks

Comment: First check if the $base_url in settings.php file (sites/default/settings.php) is not commented. If disabled its fine. It's just that it will be used as a base path of Drupal file system if turned on. You can verify that if you CSS, JS and images is loading correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As your don't have the Gui error reporting running, you can check it out through the database with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM watchdog ORDER BY wid DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Also place this in the very beginning of your index.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

Good luck!